# re-mapping media keys on a USB keyboard

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

Is it possible to re-map the media keys (volume, reload, etc) on a USB keyboard so that the order matches the one on my laptop? I want to re-map ONLY the ones on the USB keyboard.

I've tried autohotkey, but that would seem to re-map both the USB and built in keyboard which would defeat the purpose - i.e. if I "re-map key 174 to key 175" (move the mute to volume down) it switches them on both laptop and USB keyboard.

I tried pulling the keyboard apart to see if I could re-solder but that was a no-go because of the circuit type.

I saw mention of a keyboard.inf file that sets up the layout when the keyboard is installed but couldn't find anywhere that mentions how to edit it properly.

Any thoughts?

Windows 8 machine, Insignia NS-PNC5001 keyboard

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have seen this done for Wireless desktop keyboard from Microsoft, but it was not an easy thing. It was getting some required functionality directly from keyboard driver DLL and AHK macro was not a short one. Generally, recognizing which input is from which USB keyboard is not easy in Windows and it requires advanced techniques to achieve because this information is discarded in lower layers of the system.

Answer (score 0):

You could try hidmacro (http://www.hidmacros.eu), this program allows you per keyboard remapping.